# Add a total of summaries at the top of SQL (Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of foods (FOODS) and a table of food groups (FOOD_GROUP). I have build a list to summarize available food count for each group based on the search term entered by the user:

```
SELECT FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupID, FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupName, Count(FOODS.FoodID) AS CntOfFoodID
FROM FOOD_GROUP LEFT JOIN FOODS ON FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupID = FOODS.FoodGroupID
WHERE (((FOODS.FoodName) Like ("*" & [Forms]![FoodSearch]![search_term] & "*")))
GROUP BY FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupID, FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupName
ORDER BY FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupName;
```

[image: Food group | Count of foods matching the search term]

But now it gets tricky. I want to add a summary row at the top that list. Here is a nearly simmilar example:

[image: Ordered by Group name as above]

I guess I must do something like:

```
SELECT '0000', 'Show all foods', Count(FOODS.FoodID) AS CntOfFoodID
FROM FOODS
WHERE (((FOODS.FoodName) Like ("*" & [Forms]![FoodSearch]![search_term] & "*")))
UNION
SELECT FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupID, FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupName, Count(FOODS.FoodID) AS CntOfFoodID
FROM FOOD_GROUP LEFT JOIN FOODS ON FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupID = FOODS.FoodGroupID
WHERE (((FOODS.FoodName) Like ("*" & [Forms]![FoodSearch]![search_term] & "*")))
GROUP BY FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupID, FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupName
ORDER BY FOOD_GROUP.FoodGroupName;
```

But GROUP BY fails and if I take out GROUP BY than FoodGroupID is missing.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT '0000', 'Show all foods', Count(f.FoodID) AS CntOfFoodID
FROM FOODS as f
WHERE f.FoodName Like "*" & [Forms]![FoodSearch]![search_term] & "*"
UNION ALL
SELECT fg.FoodGroupID, fg.FoodGroupName, Count(f.FoodID) AS CntOfFoodID
FROM FOOD_GROUP fg LEFT JOIN
     FOODS as f
     ON fg.FoodGroupID = f.FoodGroupID
WHERE f.FoodName Like "*" & [Forms]![FoodSearch]![search_term] & "*"
GROUP BY fg.FoodGroupID, fg.FoodGroupName
ORDER BY 1;
```

The changes are:

- Use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`.  This is more efficient.
- The `ORDER BY` does not refer to a column name (especially one only in the second subquery).
- The use of table aliases just simplifies the query; it doesn't affect the logic or performance.

Comment: I do a ORDER BY 2 and want to keep the first SELECT always in top row though ;)

Comment: @user3305711 . . . You need to add a second key to the `ORDER BY`, something like `ORDER BY iif(FoodGroupId = "0000", 1, 2), <whatever the name of the second column is>`.

Comment: ORDER BY Iif(fg.FoodGroupID = '0000', 1, 2), fg.FoodGroupName; causes same error. I guess this is the way to go?: 
SELECT '0000' As ID, 'Show all foods' As N, Count(f.FoodID) AS CntOfFoodID
ORDER BY Iif(ID = '0000', 1, 2), N;